# Policy Tags in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, tags, policy, google-data-catalog

Is there a way to assign policy tags globally in BigQuery? Rather than entering every single table and putting it there?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Policy tag in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-policy-tags#build_a_hierarchy_of_data_classes), you can grant access to an **entire group of policy tags at once**. For example, you can grant the [Data Catalog Fine Grained Reader](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-policy-tags#build_a_hierarchy_of_data_classes) role on the Low tier.

Regarding granting BigQuery policy tags to specific columns, please refer to [Restricting access with BigQuery column-level security](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security) in which it further explains how you can manage access to specific columns by [setting a policy on a column](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#set_policy).

You should be aware of BigQuery Column-level security [Location considerations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro#location_considerations) and [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro#limitations).

Through using the UI - you would need to enter the policies one by one, but you can assign tags to multiple columns by CLI and API.

Comment: Cool, thank you:)

But what about assigining tags to specific columns? It has to be done 1 by 1?

Comment: @Norfecaz If your using UI - 1 by 1, but you can assign tags to multiple columns by CLI and API. If you have a specific use case, let me know